# Column invalid in select list even though it's in aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, window-functions

Here is my query:

```
SELECT ScriptName
      ,BranchName
      ,AVG(Passes) OVER (PARTITION BY ScriptName, BranchName) AS AvgPasses
FROM temp3
GROUP BY ScriptName, BranchName
```

Here is my error:

> Column 'temp3.Passes' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I understand `GROUP BY`. Does the `OVER PARTITION BY` mean it won't work with `GROUP BY`? I haven't been able to find anything on MSDN. If it does mean it won't work, can someone explain why? I cannot think of a circumstance in which a problem would arise from this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the `over partition by` means that it will not work with `group by`.  So remove it:

```
SELECT ScriptName, BranchName,
       AVG(Passes) AS AvgPasses
FROM temp3
GROUP BY ScriptName, BranchName;
```

Technically, the reason is because `Passes` is not in the `group by` and not in an aggregation function.

First, if `Passes` is an integer, the average will also be an integer.  If you want a floating point average, then convert the value to the appropriate type.

Second, analytic functions *do* work with `group by`.  For instance, if you wanted the sum of all the averages, you could do:

```
SELECT ScriptName, BranchName,
       AVG(Passes) AS AvgPasses,
       SUM(AVG(Passes)) over (ScriptName, BranchName) as SumAvg
FROM temp3
GROUP BY ScriptName, BranchName;
```

Ok, that seems weird.  But the `min()` and `max()` might be useful.